# how to check what users are accessing my tomcat server running in eclipse (java web development)?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, network-monitoring

I am developing a java web application and I am using Tomcat installed in Eclipse for my development. I want to see which computers are accessing my website (running on Tomcat) for testing purposes.

I tried netstat but that is not showing me the required data.

I am developing on a Red Hat desktop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Configure an `AccessLogValve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need configure in the file `server.xml` in Server/Service/Engine:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

See more in [The Valve Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)

**UPDATE**

For to see the log file using the [`tail`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) command, you need to know the *location* of this log file. Using the previously defined names in `Valve` example, we can have in a servlet or jsp:

```
<%
    String location = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + 
    java.io.File.separator + "logs" + java.io.File.separator + 
    "localhost_access_log." + new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) +
    ".txt";
%>
```

Example with `tail`:

```
tail -f /home/paul/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/logs/localhost_access_log.2013-05-30.txt
```

Comment: I guess to see the user logs I also need to add the -f tail ? Where exactly should I add that -f tail ?